# ip6tables port dropping and defaults

Tags: centos, ipv6, ip6tables

On CentOS 6, ip6tables is literally giving a nightmare on this machine.

Having

```
ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

with

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 21,22,80,443 -j DROP
ip6tables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport ! --dports 21,22,80,443 -j DROP
ip6tables -A INPUT ! -p ipv6-icmp -j DROP
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 21,22,80,443 -j DROP
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m multiport ! --dports 21,22,80,443 -j DROP
ip6tables -A OUTPUT ! -p ipv6-icmp -j DROP
```

or having the the top and bottom inverted, still doesnt help.

the IP6tables either block all ports, or allow all in/out. I have flushed the ip6tables to ensure no rules are there before putting these rules.

All that is required is to allow all traffic and to deny multiple ports for in/out for both tcp/udp

The ports above are example purpose only.

Thanks.

EDIT: reached a better stage, yet not working with inverses

```
ip6tables -F
ip6tables -X
ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -I FORWARD -j DROP --protocol tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443
```

Comment: As per my statement above, The ports above are example purpose only.

Comment: Why are you doing it like this? Why not make the `multiport` rules ACCEPT? Also, in your EDIT, you suddenly do the inverse? (dropping 22,80,443) What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You've done this:

```
# Drops all incoming TCP that's not directed to these ports,
# Preventing also answers for locally initiated connections!
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 21,22,80,443 -j DROP
# Drops all incoming UDP that's not directed to these ports,
# Preventing also answers for locally initiated connections!
ip6tables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport ! --dports 21,22,80,443 -j DROP
# Drop everything that's not icmp6, including UDP and TCP traffic
# that was allowed to pass earlier, making them obsolete.
ip6tables -A INPUT ! -p ipv6-icmp -j DROP
```

(repeat for `OUTPUT`)

Normally, you `ACCEPT` everything you want to allow, and then you drop.

```
ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 21,22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
```

I would not filter outgoing traffic, unless you have a good reason for this.

Comment: additionally, accept everything which belongs to an established connection and it should work as expected: ``-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT``